# How to create a simple indexOf() method of my own

Tags: java, for-loop, indexof

I'm trying to create a simple `indexOf()` method that returns an int value and that recognizes a string (not char) of an string array.

```
public int indexOf(String str) {

    /*Getting and return the index of the first 
     *occurrence of the specified String. Return 
     *-1 if string not in the list
     */

    for(int i = 0; i < listArray.length; i++) {
        if(listArray[i].equals(str)) {
            return str.indexOf(listArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I'm using `indexOf()` method from Java for the first return, but it always returns 0. Why is this, and is there a better way to write this method?

Comment: If you're trying to implement your own `indexOf` function (for practice I assume), wouldn't using the built-in function kind of defeat the purpose of the exercise? Maybe you should think of what the function actually does (or peek at the implementation in your JDK) and take it from there.

Comment: Without addressing the other issues in your code, It's better to just return i once you worked hard and iterated all the way to it...:)

Comment: What the heck is `listArray`?

Comment: Also for a good read, see what `equals` is all about by giving a quick look at the standard Knuth-Morris-Pratt Algorithm implementation https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/introduction-to-string-searching-algorithms/

Comment: The the indexOf method does always return the index of first occurrence of a string. And I'm now wondering why is that working only with the return value i? Why doesn't it return the same string oat other indexes? Like the word,  'hello', appears first at index 1, then it appears at index 3; and the method is going to return index 1.

Answer (score 2):

Your for-loop is fine, the problem there is that when you find it, you are returning the index where the string is in itself, and that will always be 0.

For instance, "hello" is in the position 0 for the string "hello".

You should just return `i`, like this:

```
public int indexOf(String str) {

    /* Getting and return the index of the first 
     * occurrence of the specified String. Return 
     * -1 if string not in the list
     */

    for (int i = 0; i < listArray.length; i++) {
        if (listArray[i].equals(str)) {
            // If we get here, it means that the item for position `i` is equal to `str`.
            return i; // just return `i` 
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`return i;` by definition `listArray[i]` is equal to `str`.

Answer (score 1):

Because, whenever you run `return str.indexoOf(listArray[i]);`, you already have `str` equals `listArray[i]`. Of course you are getting `0` all the time, it's equivalent to `str.indexOf(str);`

And you really don't need to do that. You have already found an element in the list that equals the given string, just return its location:

```
return i;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must return i (index) when the if condition is satisfied.

```
public int indexOf(String str) {

    for(int i = 0; i < listArray.length; i++) {
        if(listArray[i].equals(str)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have got confused. if you want to find a string from ArrayList and if you have already found the string in your `if(listArray[i].equals(str))` then all you have to do is just return that index i as you have already found it.

```
for(int i=0;i<listArray.length;i++){
        if(listArray[i].equals(str)){
            return i;
        }
    }
```

is the answer.

Always remember: If you even post the contents or sample of your listArray and sample string to find in it... It will help us better to understand where exactly you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a for loop.

1. Check if the string matches using equals.
2. If yes, return the index.
3. If you come out of the for loop, return -1.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int indexOf(String iparam){
    String astring = "" //YOUR OWN STRING
    boolean astat = false;
    List<Integer> alist = null;

    for(int i=0; i<astring.toCharArray().length; i++){
        alist = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int j=0; j<iparam.toCharArray().length; j++){
            try{
                if(astring.toCharArray()[i+j] == iparam.toCharArray()[j]){
                    alist.add(i+j);
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
        if(alist.size() == iparam.toCharArray().length){
            astat = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(astat){
        return alist.get(0);
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```